# Reorder items in recyclerview with snake effect

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a reordering of my icons in a recyclerview by following [this guide](https://betterprogramming.pub/drag-to-reorder-android-recyclerview-items-using-kotlin-afcaee1b7fb5)

The problem is that for same row, it is working as expected.But when i drag the item from one row to another they are just swapping each other.

I will give an example by adding the photo. I want to have the "snake" effect... When i move (red arrow) the icon from A to B position, i want the rest icons to move one place before (yellow arrow)[image]

Here is my code:

```
 override fun onItemMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
    if (fromPosition > -1 && toPosition > -1) {
        content.swapItems(fromPosition, toPosition)
        if (abs(fromPosition - toPosition) == 1) {
            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
        } else {
            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
            if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
                notifyItemMoved(toPosition - 1, fromPosition)
            } else {
                notifyItemMoved(toPosition + 1, fromPosition)
            }
        }
    }
```

}

```
  fun swapItems(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
        val fromNewPos = getItemPositionInGrid(fromPosition)
        val toNewPos = getItemPositionInGrid(toPosition)

 
        reorder(items, fromNewPos, toNewPos)
        for (element in items) {
            Log.d("element:", element.toString())
        }
    }

    fun <T> reorder(list: MutableList<T>, i: Int, j: Int) {
        list[i] = list.set(j, list[i])
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `reorder()` function is only swapping items. If you wanted the items to snake as if the item is re-inserting itself in the list, you need to actually do that:

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.shiftItem(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int): T =
    removeAt(fromPosition).also { add(toPosition, it) }
```

I didn't check the logic of your `onItemMoved()` code since I use ListAdapter to automate that aspect. But I think if you were going to do it the hard way like this, you would need to notifying about a whole range of items changing. Every item between the two positions, inclusive.

With ListAdapter, you don't have to worry about any of that logic. If you were using a ListAdapter, you'd have to use a copy of the list, so your `onItemMoved()` would be like:

```
override fun onItemMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
    if (fromPosition > -1 && toPosition > -1) {
        submitList(currentList.toMutableList().shiftItem(fromPosition, toPosition))
    }
}
```

---

Barebones instructions for transitioning from `RecyclerView.Adapter` to `ListAdapter`:

- Make sure your list item type is an immutable `data class`. By immutable, I mean every one of its properties is a `val`, not a `var`, and every one of its property types is also immutable.
- The items in your list must also have some ID kind of property for uniquely identifying them. If they came from a database, that's easy because you can use the item key. If they have text in them that never changes and is unique, that could be used instead.
- Create a DiffUtil.ItemCallback for it. If the above item data class was named MyItem, it would look like this:

```
object MyItemItemCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MyItem>() {
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: MyItem, newItem: MyItem) = 
        oldItem == newItem

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MyItem, newItem: MyItem) =
        oldItem.id == newItem.id
}
```

- Subclass `ListAdapter` instead of `RecyclerView.Adapter` and pass the above `object` to the superconstructor.
- Remove any property you're using to reference your list of items, because that's now handled by the superclass. Instead, you can use `currentList` when you're retrieving items in `onBindViewHolder`.
- Any time you have changes you want to make to the list order or contents, you must create a new list instance that contains the changes and pass it to `submitList()`.
- Any time you have changes to make to an individual item, you must still make a list copy and pass it to `submitList()`. For example:

```
fun changeTextOfItemAtPosition(position: Int, newText: String) {
    val newList = currentList.toMutableList()
    newList[position] = currentList[position].copy(text = newText)
    submitList(newList)
}
```

This example is just to illustrate the concept. A proper design wouldn't be doing all this in your adapter. You'd be managing your list in your ViewModel and publishing changes in a LiveData or Flow. Your Activity or Fragment would be observing/collecting the new lists and passing them to the adapter.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and the effort :) Just wanted to ask what is submitList? Do i need to declare it somehow? Sorry i am junior

Comment: It's a feature of ListAdapter. ListAdapter is an alternative to RecyclerView.Adapter that handles all of the "notify" logic for you under the hood. It also manages the list for you, so you wouldn't keep your own list property in your adapter, but instead you pass lists to it via `submitList()`. Instead of modifying a mutable list, you have to pass it a completely new list instance each time which is why I used `toMutableList()` above to create a list copy. To use ListAdapter, you do need to create an appropriate DiffUtil.ListCallback class, so you need to look up a tutorial for how to do that.

Comment: I added some basic instructions, but you'll probably need to reference a good tutorial for complete instructions and to grasp what it's doing.